# Server Side WCF Service : How to reference/interact with other server components

Tags: wcf, self-hosting

I have a fairly simple design question about interaction between a self hosted WCF Service and other business classes.

Here is the WCF service contract :

```
/// <summary>
/// Represent requests on hardware components made by a client to the controler service
/// </summary>
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IHardwareServiceCallback))]
public interface IHardwareService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void OpenLeftDrawer();

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void OpenRightDrawer();
}
```

The service implementation

```
public class HardwareService : IHardwareService
{
    public void OpenLeftDrawer()
    {

    }

    public void OpenRightDrawer()
    {

    }

}
```

A class which purpose is to handle the business logic regarding client calls on the server

```
class DrawerRequestManager
{
    // Server side Business logic to handle OpenDrawer requests from client
}
```

Hosting scenario

```
 Uri adrbase = new Uri(srvConfig.Address);
 var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(HardwareService), adrbase);
 host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IHardwareService), srvConfig.Binding, srvConfig.Address);
 host.Open();
```

Since this is the host that is managing the service instance lifetime, what is the **proper way** to handle the link between the service instance and business logic classes (`DrawerRequestManager` for exemple).

I'm using IOC container but i'm also interested in the response when not using IOC container.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: An answer depends on what the restrictions are for the lifetime of instances of `DrawerRequestManager` class. Sometimes it must be singleton, sometimes you can create as many instances as you wish - depends on how you communicate with your hardware. If you give more details what restrictions are, then something can be offered.

Comment: 'DrawerRequestManager' is a registred IOC singleton, and access to hardware is quite irrelevant here since it will be handled by other sub layers referenced by the 'DrawerRequestManager'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF uses parameterless constructor to create service objects, but there is a way to alter that. You need to implement your own instance provider.

You can inject your instance provider via `ServiceHostFactory`: [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh323725%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Alternatively you can inject instance provider by using custom attribute for your service: [see here](https://pieterderycke.wordpress.com/2011/05/09/using-an-ioc-container-to-create-wcf-service-instances/).

Either way gives you full control of how services instances are created. You can use IOC there or just call constructor manually passing any parameters you want (e.g. reference to `DrawerRequestManager` instance).

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try, but how does this interacts with PerCall InstanceContextMode configuration for exemple ? I guess that if the factory is configured to return a singleton as defined by the IOC framework, the InstanceContextMode will be ignored, right ?

Comment: Yes. InstanceContextMode defines when WCF creates instances. If it is configured to be Singleton, then it'll call your custom factory only once. If it is PerCall, then it'll call your factory for every incoming connection, but it's up to you to return same instance or different ones.